# What is the importance of cgconfig.conf?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, mount, cgroups

I am currently trying to get a deeper grasp into cgroups. I am working with Ubuntu 18.04 and installed the necessary libraries. I am following the documentation from this site:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/ch-using_control_groups

The problem that I am having is this. Systemd mounts cgroups in `/sys/fs/cgroup/*`. After installing the necessary libraries I don't get the `/etc/cgconfig.conf` file, although I can create one and then use `cgconfigparser` to get it running. Does the `cgconfig.conf` file even matter? Does it apply to the cgroups created by systemd? Now I realize that cgroup2 are coming out. I would really like some directions here. Does systemd use the `cgconfig.conf` and `cgrules.conf` files?

Comment: Ubuntu & RHEL are very different distributions of Linux. The documentation for RHEL would not apply correctly to an Ubuntu system. You should look up the Ubuntu documentation first.The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/cgroups.7.html) could be a start.

Comment: thanks for the reply @haxiel, I found what I was looking for in the man pages of cgroup-tools. If you have the package installed you can find the documentation in /usr/share/doc/cgroup-tool/ in the README_systemd file.

Comment: That's good to hear. Perhaps you can add an answer here with your findings so that it helps a future reader.